# Cannot produce .cs classes trying to do Intellitests with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, intellitest

I try to create Intellitests with Visual Studio Enterprise.

So far I had no problem creating them. (Create Intellitest - > Run etc.)
This time the .cs class is not generated although I get no errors/warnings at all.

```
Creating Project Game.Tests6
visibility: exported or assembly(Game)
Processing 0 types
Processing Game
Scanning assembly references in Game
Applying template AssemblyInfo to Game
Applying template Tests to Game
generating method bodies
flushing generated code
updating assembly references
finished
```

Does somebody else faced the same problem ??

Comment: Can you please tell me more about the project on which you are trying out IntelliTest?